# Simplexml URL Parameter Not Been Passed

Tags: php, rss, simplexml

I have the following code which I use to load the xml object but having trouble with variable value when retrieved from request.

```
$var1 = isset($_REQUEST['var1']);
$url = "http://xmlurl.com?_render=rss&td=$var1";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

The above will actually send an incorrect value with the request to xml function.

If I manually hard-code the value on the url, it returns the correct records.

```
$var1 = isset($_REQUEST['var1']);
$url = "http://xmlurl.com?_render=rss&td=valuespecified";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) returns a boolean value (true or false). Try using the following code:

```
$var1 = isset($_REQUEST['var1']) ? $_REQUEST['var1'] : 'default_value';
```

This code will check to see if `$_REQUEST['var1']` has been supplied. If it has not, the use the default value of *default_value*.

Comment: yeah! Thanks. I just noticed after echoing to screen it was actually using a 1.